# PHP How to cut string without breaking any words or HTML tags

Tags: php, html, function, substr

As title says I want to cut a string without breaking any words or HTML tags, now I found this function which sorts the html tags problem out *(slightly modified by myself)*

```
function substrhtml($str,$start,$len){

    $str_clean = substr(strip_tags($str),$start,$len);

    if(preg_match_all('/\<[^>]+>/is',$str,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){

        for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++){

            if($matches[0][$i][1] < $len){

                $str_clean = substr($str_clean,0,$matches[0][$i][1]) . $matches[0][$i][0] . substr($str_clean,$matches[0][$i][1]);

            }else if(preg_match('/\<[^>]+>$/is',$matches[0][$i][0])){

                $str_clean = substr($str_clean,0,$matches[0][$i][1]) . $matches[0][$i][0] . substr($str_clean,$matches[0][$i][1]);

                break;

            }

        }

        return $str_clean;

    }else{

        return substr($str,$start,$len);

    }

}
```

[Source](http://littlebearisland.com/entry113.html)

but it still cuts words in half mid sentence which I don't want to happen, any ideas on how to sort this?

As always any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738160/workaround-for-the-990-character-limitation-for-email-mailservers

Comment: Try This Link May Help You...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26098951/3944217

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
function substrhtml($str,$start,$len){

    $str_clean = substr(strip_tags($str),$start,$len);
    $pos = strrpos($str_clean, " ");
    if($pos === false) {
        $str_clean = substr(strip_tags($str),$start,$len);  
        }else
        $str_clean = substr(strip_tags($str),$start,$pos);

    if(preg_match_all('/\<[^>]+>/is',$str,$matches,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){

        for($i=0;$i<count($matches[0]);$i++){

            if($matches[0][$i][1] < $len){

                $str_clean = substr($str_clean,0,$matches[0][$i][1]) . $matches[0][$i][0] . substr($str_clean,$matches[0][$i][1]);

            }else if(preg_match('/\<[^>]+>$/is',$matches[0][$i][0])){

                $str_clean = substr($str_clean,0,$matches[0][$i][1]) . $matches[0][$i][0] . substr($str_clean,$matches[0][$i][1]);

                break;

            }

        }

        return $str_clean;

    }else{
        $string = substr($str,$start,$len);
         $pos = strrpos($string, " ");
        if($pos === false) {
            return substr($str,$start,$len);
        }
            return substr($str,$start,$pos);

    }

}
$string = '<h1>How to cut the string without breaking any words</h1>';
echo substrhtml($string,0,28);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

string splitting while respecting words can be accomplished using [wordwrap()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$string = 'When one thinks of luxury travel throughout the Mediterranean, a handful of destinations are bound to be at the top of the list, destinations like the French Riviera, the Grecian Islands, or the Italian coastline.';

echo current(explode('::BR::', wordwrap($string, 20, '::BR::')));
?>
```