# PHP email interrupted if content exceeds certain limit

Tags: php, html, string, email

I am using PHP `mail()` to send daily notice emails.

But I noticed that if the string, which stores the content of the mail, is too long, the email will be interrupted, i.e. only parts of the content will be displayed in the received emails.

When content string is short, the email will be complete. So it seems that PHP has some kinds of limits for the length of string.

I tried to use `echo $content;` to display the string that stores the content, the content is complete in the browser. But when the same string sent out in the email, it becomes interrupted.

Can anyone help me out with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: how long is the string?  can you post an example?

Comment: Would that help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738160/workaround-for-the-990-character-limitation-for-email-mailservers

Comment: @FMC Thanks very much!! That is exctly the problem I had and the solution works perfectly for me!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Try with the following script:**

```
mail($to, $subject, chunk_split(base64_encode($message), "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n");
```

**Explanations:**

- The email standard RFC2822 accepts only 998 chars of length per line.
- Email clients can read base64 encoded strings better.

Cheers!