# Email with PHP mail function with Ajax is bouncing when message exceed limit 1599 characters

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

I am having issue of bounce email in PHP.

Email with PHP `mail` function with AJAX is bouncing when message exceeds 1599 characters limit.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'send_renewal_email.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: { ids: checkValues },
     success:function(data){
                $("#LoadingImage").hide();
                $('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
                $('#email_sent_success').show().delay(5000).fadeOut();  
                $('#email_sent_success').html(data);
                window.location.reload();
     }
});
```

If `$message` has more then 1599 characters then mail bounces. Please help me in this matter. I tried to found solution but not succeed.

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)
```

Comment: It looks email server rejected message. What help did you expect?

Comment: Yes, You are right but what exactly issue is?

Comment: Maybe this answer help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866356/php-email-interrupted-if-content-exceeds-certain-limit?lq=1