# gmail not properly display my message

Tags: php, html, css, email, gmail

i have send one mail through php.In my browser is good to display. But in my gmail not good to display.i have attach my mail picture please help me.[image: my mail image]

```
function mail($to,$msgbody,$subject,$msgby,$content)
{
    $from = 'dass@world360.in'; 
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= $content." charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "From: ".$from."\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ".$msgby."\r\n";
    $returnPath = "-r".$from;
    if(mail($to, $subject, $msgbody, $headers, $returnPath))
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your php file code as well.

Comment: Show us the final HTML code please

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qwyh0551/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space in the middle of 'kind' is probably because there's a line break in the middle of the word. The link doesn't work because of the line break in the `href` attribute. If you get rid of all the random line breaks, your html will probably work.

## UPDATE:

I just thought I'd add this in case someone else is having the same issue: After some discussion with OP, he found out that most mail servers have a 990 character limit per line. If you don't properly format your code and have extremely long lines, the server could insert line breaks at that 990 char limit. I don't know if this is OP's issue without seeing the original message body, but it's a strong possibility.
See: [workaround for the 990 character limitation for email mailservers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738160/workaround-for-the-990-character-limitation-for-email-mailservers)

Comment: @user2830034 there's a line break in the middle of the link's URL

Comment: If you get rid of all the random line breaks, everything will probably work fine...

Comment: As someone else said, you need to post the PHP for us to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: PHP doesn't insert random line breaks. You're doing something to cause it. Without seeing your code there's no way to tell what's causing the issue.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: But I can tell you that isn't where the problem is. Where does `$msgbody` come from?

Comment: Are you sure there's no line breaks? It doesn't make sense that they would just randomly appear. Can you show me how you're loading the body?

Comment: Maybe they aren't line breaks. Maybe they're just spaces. It's hard to tell when you just dump minified html and expect someone to fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98764/discussion-between-user2830034-and-bern).

Comment: i think this one is formating problem now it's working thank you.